# How To Add Funtion ATCWhatsapp OnClick button in elementor

Tags: elementor

Please help me, my case here is that I want to add the ATCWhatsapp OnClick Button function so that the second track event can be tracked simultaneously, that's about it.

```
<script>
    function ATCWhatsapp(){
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
        fbq('track', 'Purchase',{value: 350.000, currency: 'MYR'});
        fbq('track', 'KlikWA');
  };
 </script>
```

Comment: <script>
    function ATCWhatsapp(){
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
    fbq('track', 'Purchase',{value: 350.000, currency: 'IDR'});
    fbq('track', 'KlikWA');
  };
  </script>

Comment: Tip : add the javascript tag